# Vanity URL for App profile

Tags: facebook-apps, vanity-url

I really need your help here, I'm searching for soltion for so long.

I have an App and I want its profile page to get a vanity URL: facebook.com/myappname .
Now I navigate to https://www.facebook.com/username , but I can't see my App profiles on the list - I see only my business pages.

What can I do to get this URL already ?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

For apps the url is ment to be http://apps.facebook.com/myappname.

read [Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)

Comment: Not the app canvas page, but the app profile. Right now the URL is http://facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=XXX and i want it to be http://facebook.com/appname - yet i can't find it on http://facebook.com/username , why?